# Why is the entire html body stuck at the top of the viewport?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am writing a commandline tool for myself to generate a quick html bootstrap starter and I have an index page, which is supposed to include a basic navbar at the top and a footer that sticks to the bottom of the page. I have used this same template before for other projects and it worked perfectly. But for some reason it won't work now. all the content is stuck at the top of the page. If I inspect the page, the entire `html` tag contents are at the top of the page and most of the page is blank document. Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <title>Bootstrap Starter</title>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column">
    <!-- Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <span class="navbar-text">
        <a href="/">Bootstrap Starter</a>
      </span>
    </nav>

    <!-- Content --> 
    <div class="container content"></div>

    <!-- Footer-->
    <div class="footer">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><!-- Footer bar-->
        <div class="p-4 mt-5 bg-light text-center"><small>© Your Name, </small></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the css:

```
* custom styles */


/* Sticky footer */
html, body {
    height: 100% !important;
}

.content {
    flex: 1 0 auto !important;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this isn't producing the desired result? Thanks.

Comment: check it properly u r code working now

Comment: @AmareshSM Sorry but I have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: just click run code snippet it works perfectly footer is present at the bottom and nav is at the top

Comment: He's saying he changed the code in your question and now it works. Which is really not how SO operates, but I guess that works.

Comment: i haven't modified any code just inserted the code into snippet

Comment: Okay I see now. Why does it work when the custom css is added to a `style` tag but not when the css is loaded from an external file? I even tried loading it before the bootstrap css and that didn't work either. Totally confused.

Comment: @AmareshSM I don't understand why it works, but thanks for the solution!

Comment: internal css will get more priority than external css. internal css properties of body & .content will override the external css properties.

Comment: @AmareshSM But in the external stylesheet I used the `!important` keyword. Why doesn't that make it highest priority? Still not getting this.

Comment: Rolled back to version 1 since the edit ended up removing the syntax error that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your css was moved into the document and now it works. What this indicates to me is an issue with the external stylesheet. I notice that you have 2 custom stylesheets, 1 before 3rd party stylesheets and 1 after. The browser respects the order, so if your code was in the first stylesheet the 3rd party stylesheets may have overwritten your custom rules.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am using the `!important` keyword, and I also rearranged the external stylesheets in the right order to prioritize my custom styles, but still the same thing. I'm just at a loss. Especially because I have another project that uses almost this exact same html and css and it works.

Comment: Is the filepath correct? Open your browsers dev tools and look in the network to see if the custom stylesheet was fetched correctly. (Or sources tab if your not using a server)

Comment: I just discovered the problem and it was literally a syntax error in the comment at the top of the custom stylesheet. So the file was loading but the css wasn't interpreted by the browser. Sigh. That escaped everyone who commented on this too. The human brain really didn't evolve to see minute details. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: It might have been easier if someone hadn't *changed your code*.... Lol. Glad you found it.